# Is there a way to display dynamically selected components without use of structural directives

Tags: angular

I want to allow users to select items/components ***dynamically*** from a list. The selected items will be displayed in a gird-like DOM, the catch is that the display elements are different components with their own view.

Rough class structure is below. In theory this should work but I am struggling to figure out how to set up the view?

I was thinking that parent would have `*ngFor`, of course, but I want to avoid using `*ngIf` as I am potentially looking of eventually having dozens of different child elements and need to abstract code as much as possible. *Ideally*, to add a new component all I would have to do is create a child component object and add it to the list in parent component.

**I am of course open to other implementations of this as I am fairly new to angular.**

I cannot share the actual code, unfortunately, but here is a rough idea of what structure I have.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mx2xli **(Draft only - this will not display anything)**

[image: UML DRAFT]

Comment: This is doable if I understand you correctly. You’d have to create and mount the childComponents though - using a resolver factory. Is that what you mean?

Comment: More here: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: This is absolutely it @MikeOne

Comment: Cool. Goodluck with your app!